# Change function not firing, javascript dynamic form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm not sure why this is not firing. When I test the code, the forms appear, but when I select from the first form, noting happens. I am sure that for whatever reason, the .change(function) is not working.

```
<?php
require("scripts/dbconnect.php");

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT name FROM sets');
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

?>
<select id="first-choice">
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <option><?=$row["name"]?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>

<br />

<select id="second-choice">
    <option>Please choose from above</option>
</select>

<script language=JavaScript>
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
    $("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("select#first-choice option").filter(":selected").val());
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is that script tag actually after the select, such as in your question? or is it in the head of your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first, make sure JQuery is included on the page (it isn't in your post).  And second, make sure your code is called when the DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#first-choice").change(function() {
      $("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("select#first-choice option").filter(":selected").val());
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Jquery wasn't included